# Hamburger icon not opening

Tags: javascript, python, django

```js
$('.open-overlay').click(function() {
  var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
    nav_item_1 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(1)'),
    nav_item_2 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(2)'),
    nav_item_3 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(3)'),
    nav_item_4 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(4)'),
    nav_item_5 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(5)'),
    top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
    middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
    bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

  overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
  if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

    top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4');
  } else {
    top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse');
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="home">
  <div class="open-overlay">
    <span class="bar-top"></span>
    <span class="bar-middle"></span>
    <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Here is my code when being ran on code snippet, thank you for your assistance in advance :)

```
$('.open-overlay').click(function() {
  var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
    nav_item_1 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(1)'),
    nav_item_2 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(2)'),
    nav_item_3 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(3)'),
    nav_item_4 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(4)'),
    nav_item_5 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(5)'),
    top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
    middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
    bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

  overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
  if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {

    top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down')
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4');
  } else {
    top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up')
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse');
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="home">
  <div class="open-overlay">
    <span class="bar-top"></span>
    <span class="bar-middle"></span>
    <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

My hamburger icon is currently not opening, I figure that it is a problem with my JavaScript. Any other tips and tricks when coming to JavaScript are very much welcome as I am a beginner, so your assistance would be very much appreciated.

java.js

```js
$('.open-overlay').click(function () {
  var overlay_navigation = $('.overlay-navigation'),
    nav_item_1 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(1)'),
    nav_item_2 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(2)'),
    nav_item_3 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(3)'),
    nav_item_4 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(4)'),
    nav_item_5 = $('nav li:nth-of-type(5)'),
    top_bar = $('.bar-top'),
    middle_bar = $('.bar-middle'),
    bottom_bar = $('.bar-bottom');

  overlay_navigation.toggleClass('overlay-active');
  if (overlay_navigation.hasClass('overlay-active')) {
    top_bar.removeClass('animate-out-top-bar').addClass('animate-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-out-middle-bar').addClass('animate-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-out-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-up').addClass('overlay-slide-down');
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4');
  } else {
    top_bar.removeClass('animate-top-bar').addClass('animate-out-top-bar');
    middle_bar.removeClass('animate-middle-bar').addClass('animate-out-middle-bar');
    bottom_bar.removeClass('animate-bottom-bar').addClass('animate-out-bottom-bar');
    overlay_navigation.removeClass('overlay-slide-down').addClass('overlay-slide-up');
    nav_item_1.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-reverse');
    nav_item_2.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-1-reverse');
    nav_item_3.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-2-reverse');
    nav_item_4.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-3-reverse');
    nav_item_5.removeClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4').addClass('slide-in-nav-item-delay-4-reverse');
  }
});
```

my html

```html
<div class="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section class="home">
  <div class="open-overlay">
    <span class="bar-top"></span>
    <span class="bar-middle"></span>
    <span class="bar-bottom"></span>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Kindly add all code in a code snippet so that others can run it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to see what's going on as you're not including your CSS, and there's a lot of unnecessary code there (everything relating to your nav items).

I broke out a simple example that works:

```js
document.getElementById('open-overlay').addEventListener('click', e => {
        document.getElementById('overlay-navigation').classList.toggle('active');
    })
```

```css
.bar {
    display: block;
    height:5px;
    width:20px;
    margin:2px 0;
    background-color: black;
}
#overlay-navigation {
    display: none;
}
#overlay-navigation.active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="home">
  <div id="open-overlay">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </div>
</section>

<div id="overlay-navigation">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="The beginning">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Curious?">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="I got game">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Only the finest">Works</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-content="Don't hesitate">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Things that I changed:

- `open-overlay` and `overlay-navigation` are now ids and not classes
- `overlay-navigation` has it's `display` set to `none` by default (hidden)
- `.active` simply sets the `display` back to `block`

Comment: hello, sorry about not adding my css, totally forgot about that, i will add it now

Comment: @Nandipa I added your JS, HTML, and CSS to a new page and ran it - the menu is opening and closing fine. This suggests that there's possibly something else the issue. Are you seeing anything particular error?

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but as a new dev, you should try to move away from jquery, as there's generally no longer a need for it. Some trivial examples of converting jquery to pure js: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: My hamburger icon is not opening up to my navbar and when i try to run my code snippet its giving me this,   "   Error: {
  "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 378,
  "colno": 9
} "

Comment: `$` is the shortcut to use jquery (it has a long history, but in general is no longer needed with the modern web). To make no changes to your code, you need to include jquery before your scripts - e.g. add `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` above your scripts in your html page